# Validate Gmail account and retrieve basic profile info

Tags: gmail-api

Is there a way to validate account existence and retrieve basic gmail account info such as name and photo url using only email ?

Previously it was possible to get account photoUrl using the following endpoint:

```
http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/<hereYourUserIdOrYourEmail>?alt=json
```

but it was shut down.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Picasa Web Albums Data API was turned down last January 2019. They have provided a [Migration Guide to Google Photos Library API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_migration). Try [Google Photos Library API](https://developers.google.com/photos/) as a new way to way to interact with a user's Google Photos library. For the name, I think it is not possible to for Gmail API, since it only returns the response specified [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile#response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access that information with the gmail-api. If you are the admin of a g suite domain, you could use the directory API to obtain that info.

If the application is not intended for a specific domain, you can implement google oauth2 with JavaScript in the front-end, the user would have to authenticate and this way you'll be able to access the basic information. You need to create a project in cloud.google.com and get credentials (a clientID is needed in the code). More explanation here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

Implementation example (only clientID missing):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="#clientId">
    <title>Oauth2 web</title>

    <!-- Google library -->
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

    <!-- Jquery library to print the information easier -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap library for the button style-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="profileinfo">
</div>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

<script>
            function onSignIn(googleUser) {
              var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
              console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
              console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
              console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
              console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.

              $("#profileinfo").append("<h2>Sup " + profile.getName() + ", welcome home my friend</h2>");
              $("#profileinfo").append("<img style='width:250px;height:250px' src='" + profile.getImageUrl() + "'><br><br>");
              $("#profileinfo").append("<p>Your email is: " + profile.getEmail() + "</p>");

            }
        </script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</button>

<script>
            function signOut() {
               var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
               auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                 console.log('User signed out.');
               $("#profileinfo").empty();
               $("#profileinfo").append("<h2>Goodbye old friend</h2>");
               });
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```